# 1=1 in a managedQuery

Tags: android, sqlite

new to android/java programming. Quick question. In php/mysql I use 1=1 a lot when building dynamic select queries. It saves some extra steps (i can append AND onto each part of the select query and finish it with 1=1). Doing this with managedQuery gives me an empty cursor when querying the calllog. Is this something managedQuery is not allowing or is it sqlite or what? I realize I can write smarter code but it was such a nice short cut in php, wondering if its possible in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Just don't use it with `OR` . :-)

Comment: It sounds like there is a bug somewhere in your code. According to my test, SQLite works fine when using WHERE 1=1.

Comment: I confirm `WHERE 1=1` works fine in SQLite. I also used some `WHERE 1=0` to validate how different aggregated functions on empty sets were returned.

Comment: I'm thinking it must be a limitation of managedQuery() then. anyone else care to chime in?

Comment: I'd like to see the actual query that's getting sent in. there have been more then a few times where i've gotten funky errors when I was building up the sql string, that I couldn't figure out until I had it show me what the final built string that was being passed in was then i noticed it was building it wrong and it was something that would of been very hard to see otherwise. so could you please show us at least one of the built query strings so we help you make sure it's really building the string properly?